# Jersey 2.2 Client POST request to Parse.com utf-8 issue

Tags: parse-platform, jackson, jersey-2.0, dropwizard, jersey-client

I am a begginer in Dropwizard / Jersey so please bear with me. I am creating request from my Dropwizard application resource:

```
Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment)
                .using(new JerseyClientConfiguration())
                .build("my-app-name");

String response = client
                .target("https://api.parse.com/1/functions/myFunction")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("X-Parse-Client-Key", "mysecredclientcode")
                .header("X-Parse-Session-Token", "mysecretsessiontoken")
                .header("X-Parse-Application-Id", "mysecretapplicationid")
                .post(Entity.text(
                        "{\"postId\":\"xP0Jc2lrqS\"}"
                ));
```

I think I tried all possible variations of Entity.* followed by MediaType.* with no luck.

This should work according to documentation. And I can call other endpoints of my app locally this way with no problems. But requests to parse.com return following entity:

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid utf-8 string was provided"}
```

When I curl from bash I get expected response. I feel like I tried everything, can you please point me in the right direction, what am I doing wrong here?

curl request that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: mysecretapplicationid" \
  -H "X-Parse-Client-Key: mysecretclientkey" \
  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: mysecretsessiontoken" \
  -d '{"postId":"xP0Jc2lrqS"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/myFunction
```

Comment: The weird thing is, the default Content-Type when you don't specify it in cURL is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I wonder if that has anything to do with it. What happens if you explicitly set the Content-Type in curl to application/json?

Comment: modifying curl does not make a difference when I add -H "Content-Type: application/json" \

Comment: Try using a POJO and let the framework serialize it, instead of using a string.

Comment: This is actually the first this I tried with no luck since this is exactly what I'm going for and I was fearful that this is what's causing the problem: .post(Entity.json(
                        new GetPostConfig.Builder()
                                .postId("xP0Jc2lrqS")
                                .build()
                )

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still facing this issue, I solved this adding in my maven project these properties:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Regards,